# How to divide 100% to no of records conditionally

Tags: apex

I am using the below method on button click

```
public PageReference Adjusments(){
    system.debug('@@@@@@'+selectedVal);
    if(selectedVal ==' '){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Warning,'No Smart Category is selected'));
    }
    else{

 I = [select id,Name,Active__c,Auto_Invest_Percent__c,Symbol__c,Smart_Category__c,Shares__c,Price__c,Value__c from Investment__c where Investment__C.Smart_Account__r.Name=:smartaccountId ];

        Integer count = 0;
        for(Investment__c i: I){
            If(i.Smart_Category__c==selectedVal){
                count++;
                Integer z = (100)/count;
                i.Auto_Invest_Percent__c =z; 
            }else
            {
                i.Active__c =false; 
                i.Auto_Invest_Percent__c =0;

            }

        }
        update i;
}
PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/manage_Investments');
    return pg;

}
```

I want when `(i.Smart_Category__c==selectedVal)` which is the else part 100% should get divided among the records which meet `(i.Smart_Category__c==selectedVal)` condition.

Comment: In other words, do you want to get the percentage of the of records that has Smart_Category__c equals to selectedVal?

Comment: No I want to divide 100% (which is static number ) among the records which has Smart_Category__c equals to selectedVal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify that query condition:

> ```
> [select id,Name,Active__c,Auto_Invest_Percent__c,Symbol__c,Smart_Category__c,Shares__c,Price__c,Value__c from Investment__c where Investment__C.Smart_Account__r.Name=:smartaccountId ];
> ```

to filter which records has Smart_Category__c equals selectedVal.

```
List<Investment__c> I = [select id,Name,Active__c,Auto_Invest_Percent__c,Symbol__c,Smart_Category__c,Shares__c,Price__c,Value__c from Investment__c where Investment__C.Smart_Account__r.Name=:smartaccountId and Smart_Category__c = :selectedVal];
```

then calculate the total, as your are doing now, using the size of the list:

```
Integer z = (100)/(I.size());
```

But if you don´t want to change the query, add a counter to count the Investments that has this Smart_Category__c:

```
Integer count = 0;

for(Investment__c in: I){
    if(in.Smart_Category__c == selectedVal){
        count++;
    }
    /*... rest of your code*/
}

Integer z = 100/count;
```

And if you want to populate the `i.Auto_Invest_Percent__c` for each Investment__c, you will have to code two for loops, one for calculating `z` and an other for populating `Auto_Invest_Percent__c`.

```
Integer count = 0;

for(Investment__c in: I){
    if(in.Smart_Category__c == selectedVal){
        count++;
    }
}

Integer z = 100/count;

for(Investment__c in: I){
    if(in.Smart_Category__c == selectedVal){
        in.Auto_Invest_Percent__c = z;
       /*... rest of your code*/
    }
    else{
       in.Auto_Invest_Percent__c = 0; 
       /*... rest of your code*/
    }
    /*... rest of your code*/
}
```

Comment: Apex is not a case-sensitive lanaguge, variable `I` and `i` will result in an error "Duplicate variable: i"

Comment: Yes thanks, I didn´t realize it when editing the question code.

Comment: I have edited my current code. Now if i have 3 records out of which is one is not equal. The % is getting divided as 100, 50, 0. It should be 50, 50,0.

Comment: This is because the first time you get 100/1 and the second time you get 100/2. You have to use two for loops, one for calculating the total amount of records that fit your condition, then calculate the division and then the for loop for populating Auto_Invest_Percent__c  of the records. See updated solution.

Comment: If u dont mind can u please update the code..with your logic..

Comment: Of course, I have already updated the code. Please mark it as solution if it is, to let us know you have resolved your problem.